# get json token value via remote URL in android/java

Tags: java, android, json

hi there I have a simple json that I store in my web page (only pure json):

**http://example.com/file.json**

```
{
    "data": {
        "message": "This is a text",
    },
}
```

Now I want parse it with android and get message value:

In PHP is so simple like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://example.com/file.json');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->message;
```

But how can I do it for android?

I try write the code:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("http://example.com/file.json")
JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
String message = data.getString("message");
```

But I know it is wrong

Comment: You have to first send a requst to the server, and than parse the response with **JSONObject**.

Comment: Will you answer control.

Comment: @partiz if so please accept/vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>JSONObject json = new JSONObject("http://example.com/file.json")</del> **is wrong**.

Read JSON file from remote website.

**Example:**

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/file.json");
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(url.openStream());
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(tokener);
JSONObject data = obj.getJSONObject("data");
String message = data.getString("message");
```

**JSONTokener** [javadoc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONTokener.html)

*Dependencies*

**json:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

**Jackson:**

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks but I got this error: `Error:(118, 31) error: constructor JSONTokener in class JSONTokener cannot be applied to given types;
required: String
found: InputStream
reason: actual argument InputStream cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion`